# $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -8} \frac {8 − |x|} {8 + x} \ $ How do I solve?

Tags: calculus, limits

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to -8^+} \frac {8 − |x|} {8 + x} &=
\lim_{x\to -8^+} \frac {8 − x} {8 + x}\\
&= \frac {8 − 8} {8 + -8} \\ &= 0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to -8^-} \frac {8 − |x|} {8 + x} &=
\lim_{x\to -8^-} \frac {8 − (-x)} {8 + x} \\
&= \frac {8 + − 8} {8 + -8} \\ &= 0 
\end{align*}

However, the answer key says that I am wrong. Where have I failed?

Comment: As $x \to -8^{+}$, $x < 0$.  What does that tell you about $|x|$?  What is $-(-8)$?

Comment: You failed in the last statement. If functions in numerator and denominator both tend to zero, then a correct limit of a fraction is 'unknown' (until you use some other calculations), but not $0$.

Comment: Me or N.F. Taussig?

Comment: @user137452 You did. Look at the answers below for detailed description.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -8} \frac{8-|x|}{8+x} = \lim_{x<0,\ x\rightarrow
-8} \frac{8+x}{8+x}=1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{8-|x|}{8+x}=\frac{8-x}{8+|x|}$, so $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-8}\frac{8-|x|}{8+x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-8}\frac{8-x}{8+|x|}=\frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow-8}(8-x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow-8}(8+|x|)}=\frac{16}{16}=1$$.

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow-8}(8+|x|)=16\neq0$, so the above works.

Comment: So I do not need to see of the limit exist?

Comment: @user137452-The limit on the RHS is obvious.

Comment: It isn't obvious to me. Explain.

Comment: @user137452-Both of the limit of $8-x$ and $8+|x|$ are 16.

Comment: Are you testing the + and - sides?

Comment: Please show me. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Alfred's equality gives you a continuous function in place of your discontinuous one. *All* limits of the function on the LHS are equal to the RHS's, but the RHS being continuous means you only need plug in the value to obtain the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with respect to your answer, the biggest mistake is obviously in
$$\frac {8 + 8} {8 + -8} = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac {8 + -8} {8 + -8} = 0$$
Here you have $0$ in the denominator, which makes both fractions undefined. Moreover, whether you approach $-8$ from the left or from the right, you are still dealing with a negative number in a small enough neighborhood around $-8$, so you may assume that $x<0$. The correct result, as have been suggested by other answerers, is
$$\lim_{x\to-8} \frac{8-\vert x\vert}{8+x}=\lim_{x\to -8}\frac{8+x}{8+x}=1$$

Comment: Why are you not required to test both sides of the limit and in your case not at all?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ stand for a number infinitesimally close to 0, but not equal to 0.

Now, we have \begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to -8^+} \frac {8 − |x|} {8 + x} &
\end{align*}

becomes

\begin{align*}
\frac {8 − |-8+\alpha|} {8 + -8+\alpha} &
\end{align*}.

Since |-8+$\alpha$|=8, we thus end up with $\alpha$/$\alpha$=1, for the first limit.  Similarly reasoning yields 1 for the second limit.